# TRIAC protection for general domestic use

Tags: triac, transient, over-voltage-protection

I am designing a smart switch for switching 220 - 240 VAC outlets for domestic use at a maximum of 16A.  The load could be a washing machine, a toaster, a vacuum cleaner or any general home appliance (or any combination thereof).

I have seen a combination of an R-C network (or "snubber") as well as a VDR (or MOV) across the TRIAC for protection, but I am unsure how to calculate the values of those components to provide an all-round protection for this general application as I do not know the inductive characteristics of the load beforehand. Is it possible to design an "all-purpose" protection circuit for the TRIAC and if so, could someone perhaps provide some guidance on making those calculations for the component values.

I have also found some "ACS" TRAICs ( from ST Microelectronics (ACST12) which have built in crowbar technology, but unsure whether these would be suitable in my application without any other protection for the TRIAC.

Any information would be helpful, thank you.

Comment: There's no going around prototyping the circuit and using sufficient instrumentation to measure (with wide bandwidth) the voltages in an actual TRIAC you're using, in the actual layout you put together, and with some real-life appliances. You can start with some assumptions, but nothing beats lab testing, and you can't expect to get something that simulates OK in spice and is adequate. At least not without lots of experience to dictate what parasitic effects to model (and how).